# Issue while installing mysql.connector in Python 2-7 after migrating from 2.6

Tags: python, mysql

Mysql.connector used to work as expected in Python 2.6 but as i wanted to use argparse, i installed 2.7 version. I am facing below errors while installing connector to this version. I am not sure how to resolve them.

```
**Error while importing connector:**

 [/usr/local/bin ] # python
 Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr 19 2016, 19:36:47)
 [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import mysql.connector
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
  >>>

**Paths located**

[~ ] # which python2.6
/usr/bin/python2.6
[~ ] # which python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
[~ ] # which python
/usr/local/bin/python
[~ ] # ls -l /usr/local/bin/py*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      84 Apr 19 18:10 /usr/local/bin/pydoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Apr 19 21:57 /usr/local/bin/python ->      /usr/bin/python2.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 19 18:10 /usr/local/bin/python2 ->  python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6214541 Apr 19 19:36 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1674 Apr 19 19:36 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 19 18:10 /usr/local/bin/python2-config ->     python2.7-config
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 Apr 19 18:10 /usr/local/bin/python-config -> python2-config
 [~ ] # pip -V
 pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)

 **Trying to install mysql connector for python 2.7**

  [/usr/src ] # rpm -i  mysql-connector-python-2.0.4-1.el7.noarch.rpm
   error: Failed dependencies:
    python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by mysql-connector-python-2.0.4-1.el7.noarch
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing the `mysql-connector-python` package using `pip` with the same version of Python that you're using in the REPL where you're trying to do `import mysql.connector`. So, if you're trying to install `mysql-connector-python`, try to install it with `pip2.7` which should be in the same directory as the `python2.7` binary on your machine.

Answer (score -1):

A simple and not elegant way, is to install an older build of the connector.
As in my case, mysql-connector-python-1.2.3-1......rpm is installed in the similar environment.

BTW, the checking is by rpm -q python, then you will realize the system is initially with python2.6 installed:
python-2.6.8-0.15.1

The python2.7 installed later on does not change the system information.